# "Error writing file, read-only filesystem" when file system says it's read-write enabled

Tags: files, filesystems

I'm currently trying to update the network settings on an embedded Linux device. This is typically done by modifying the contents of file /opt/etc/network/interfaces. The file system mounted at /opt/ is by default RO, however, we temporarily change this to RW while we update the file contents by using the command

```
mount -o remount,rw /opt
```

I confirm that the file system has been updated to RW by looking at the contents of /proc/mounts

[image]

I believe the file system is now read-writable since I see the RW letters.

However, when I go to modify the file, I get a read-only error.

[image]

This confuses me. The file system is read-write per /proc/mounts, however, I'm still getting a file system error. I'm not a file system master, but I have three theories of what's going:

1. The storage device has some sort of memory lock (i.e. switch) enabled.
2. This file actually lives in a nest file system, so it's not actually hosted on /opt
3. I'm a dummy and am missing something obvious.

Comment: Maybe it's SquashFS?

Comment: Does anything interesting appear in the system logs (especially the kernel logs), either at the time of mounting or at the time of the access attempt? Regarding 2, check `df /path/to/file`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Alright, I think we're onto something. It says the file is mounted on "/opt/vfat". I guess i'm a file system rookie because that makes no since to me given the file location.

Comment: There must be a symbolic involved. Check `namei /path/to/file` or `readlink -f /path/to/file`

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' That's what I was thinking too and just confirmed it. I would say your response of using "df /path/to/file" was the answer I need since I didn't know what command to use. Feel free to type up an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in your question proves that the file `/opt/etc/network/interfaces` is actually on the `/opt` filesystem. One of the directories on that path could be a mount point. Or, more likely, either `/opt/etc/network/interfaces` itself or one of the directories `/opt/etc` or `/opt/etc/network` is actually a symbolic link whose target is on another filesystem.

To see what filesystem `/opt/etc/network/interfaces` is actually on, run

```
df /opt/etc/network/interfaces
```

If `/opt/etc/network/interfaces` itself is a symbolic link, this reports the location of the symbolic link. Check with `ls -l /opt/etc/network/interfaces`.

Linux provides a convenient utility [`namei`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/namei.1.html) to see all the symbolic links involved in a path.

```
namei /opt/etc/network/interfaces
```